# Pyspark dataframe - select rows that fails

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Is that possible to perform set of operations on dataframe (adding new columns, replace some existing values, etc) and do not fast fail on first failed rows, but instead perform full transformation and separately return rows that has been processed with errors?

Example:
it's more like pseudocode, but the idea must be clear:

```
df.withColumn('PRICE_AS_NUM', to_num(df["PRICE_AS_STR"]))
```

to_num - is my custom function of transformation string to number.

assuming I have some records where price can't be cast to number - I want to get those records in separate dataframe.

I see an approach, but it will make code a little ugly (and not quite productive):
do a filter with try catch - if exception happen - filter those records into separate df..
What if I have many of such transformations... Is any better way?

Comment: Could you provide a small example with some sample inputs, operations, why they would fail, and desired outputs? Please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-dataframe-examples).

Comment: you can do a native python try/except

Comment: @pault, added example.

Comment: @pratiklodha I can't wrap whole process - it will fail on first record. I want all of them.

Answer (score 2):

I think one approach would be to wrap your transformation with a `try`/`except` function that returns a boolean. Then use `when()` and `otherwise()` to filter on the boolean. For example:

```py
def to_num_wrapper(inputs):
    try:
        to_num(inputs)
        return True
    except:
        return False

from pyspark.sql.functions import when
df.withColumn('PRICE_AS_NUM',
              when(
                    to_num_wrapper(df["PRICE_AS_STR"]),
                    to_num(df["PRICE_AS_STR"])
              ).otherwise('FAILED')
)
```

Then you can filter on the columns where the value is `'FAILED'`.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I had something like that in mind! Unfortunately, I'll need to do it for many columns, also derived data type of those columns won't make much sense...

Answer (score 1):

**Preferred option**

Always prefer built-in SQL functions over UDF. There safe to execute and much faster than a Python UDF. As a bonus they follow SQL semantics - if there is a problem on the line, the output is `NULL` - undefined.

**If you go with UDF**

Follow the same approach as built-in functions.

```py
def safe_udf(f, dtype):
    def _(*args):
        try:
            return f(*args)
        except:
            pass
    return udf(_, dtype)

to_num_wrapper = safe_udf(lambda x: float(x), "float")

df = spark.createDataFrame([("1.123", ), ("foo", )], ["str"])

df.withColumn("num", to_num_wrapper("str")).show()
# +-----+-----+
# |  str|  num|
# +-----+-----+
# |1.123|1.123|
# |  foo| null|
# +-----+-----+
```

While swallowing exception might be counter-intuitive it just a matter of following SQL conventions.

**No matter which one you choose**:

Once you adjust you with one of the above, handling malformed data is just a matter of applying `DataFrameNaFunctions` (`.na.drop`, `.na.replace`).